# How do I stores columns values retrieved from a table into a variable in my shell script and use it for my entire script

Tags: shell

I've seen below script in this forum, its useful

```
echo "This will print the Date"  
VALUE=`sqlplus -silent apps/Z4vRD3me <<END 
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off 
select sysdate from dual  
exit; 
END`

# xx=$(echo 'select sysdate from dual' | sqlplus -silent apps/Z4vRD3me)  
echo $VALUE 
echo "End of SQL"
```

But after exiting from SQL*PLUS also, I want to use the sysdate value stored in 'VALUE' variable in further unix script

after executing this script we will come back to unix mode. then If I type 'echo $VALUE'/'$VALUE' its saying "ksh: SQL*Plus::  not found".

Can you please give me solution to store the required column values for my entire unix script?

Thanks

Comment: hi, if it is ksh you should add a tag for that

Comment: The message "ksh: SQL*Plus:: not found" is a clear indication that things are not working as you hope. Where would your script be getting the word 'SQL*Plus' when you reference it as sqlplus? Is there other code you're not showing us? Your commented line for xx=$(..) looks about right for storing a value. what's wrong with it? Learn to use the shell debugging `set -vx` AND stop using backticks for command-substitution, use `$( .. cmd .. )`. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to use sql to generate valid shell commands and capture it to a spool file. Then source the spoolfile

```
TMPFILE=tmp_$$.sh
sqlplus -silent user/password <<END
set feedback off
set head off
spool $TMPFILE
Select 'export value=' || To_Char(Sysdate) from dual;
Select 'export TblCount=' || To_Char(count(*)) from all_tables;
spool off
exit
END

#Run the commands you generated in the current process and remove temp
. $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE

echo $value 
echo $TblCount
```